# Javascript Input type

Tags: javascript

In javascript we use  input type = file .. to open up a file browser pop-up .. is there a way to limit access to folders .. I want to select a folder then ftp all the files in the folder .. so i need access upto only the folder level and not file level .. i guess it would be tedious to go an manually select every file from the folder and then ftp .. is there a way to do that.. 
Also, how can i set the file-browser pop-up window path to a default one ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take advantage of Flash or similar to enabled extended file upload options.

e.g. [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org/project) will allow you to filter out:

- file types: *.gif, *.doc, *.zip etc.
- file size: max etc.
- multiple files

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that in standard JavaScript - it's a functionality that is browser dependent.

It may be exposed via Flash or some other custom browser plugin.